# Read committed data within a transaction in sql server

Tags: .net, sql-server, ado.net

I want to read data without dirty reads in the middle of a transaction. Is that possible?

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[Tbl](
    [Id] [int] NOT NULL,
    [Detail] [varchar](50) NULL)

insert into Tbl values(1,'abc')
select * from Tbl where id = 1

begin tran
update Tbl set Detail = 'def' where id = 1

select * from Tbl

-- here I need "abc" as a return because the transaction is not yet committed.
-- It is in the middle of it. But it is returning me "def" only.
select * from Tbl (readcommitted)

rollback tran

select * from Tbl where id = 1
drop table Tbl
```

Assigning it to a variable before update is not what I'm looking for, because I will run the scripts in a for loop inside a single transaction.

eg:

```
transaction.begin
foreach file
sqlcmd.executenonquery(<my script goes here>)
transaction.end
```

Comment: If you're within the same transaction, you'll already be able to read the changes you did to the table; the transaction would have already locked the table to the transaction...

Comment: how can read the data from original data, which is committed one?

Comment: What do you mean, read the original data?

Comment: data before update statement or actual committed data that was there in that table before the transaction begin.

Comment: Why not put the `SELECT *` *before* the `UPDATE`?

Comment: Simple answer: you're reading the data within that transaction - if you want to look at/manipulate the data as was before the transaction started then you need to store that "start data" somewhere; either in a variable or a temp table.

Comment: You can also use an [output clause](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/queries/output-clause-transact-sql) with all DML statements to capture the original values into another table, temp table or table variable, e.g.: `declare @SomeTableVariable table (Detail varchar(50)); update Tbl set Detail='def' output deleted.Detail into @SomeTableVariable where id = 1;`

Comment: You could open a separate connection perhaps. But this smells of an XY problem: what exactly are you trying to *achieve*?